# $httpBackend in AngularJs Jasmine unit test

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm unable to get my unit test to work properly. I have a $scope array that starts out empty, but should be filled with an $http.get(). In the real environment, there'd be approx 15 or so objects in the array, but for my unit test I just grabbed 2. For the unit test, I have:

```
expect($scope.stuff.length).toBe(2);
```

But jasmine's error is: Expected 0 to be 2.

here's my controller.js:

```
$scope.stuff = [];
$scope.getStuff = function () {
    var url = site.root + 'api/stuff';
    $http.get(url)
        .success(function (data) {
            $scope.stuff = data;
        })
        .error(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
};
```

and my controller.spec.js is:

```
/// <reference path="../../../scripts/angular-loader.min.js" />
/// <reference path="../../../scripts/angular.min.js" />
/// <reference path="../../../scripts/angular-mocks.js" />
/// <reference path="../../../scripts/angular-resource.js" />
/// <reference path="../../../scripts/controller.js" />
beforeEach(module('ui.router'));
beforeEach(module('ngResource'));
beforeEach(module('ngMockE2E'));
beforeEach(module('myApplication'));
var $scope;
var controller;
var httpLocalBackend;

beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller, $injector) {
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();
    controller = $controller("StuffController", {
        $scope: $scope
    });
}));

beforeEach(inject(function ($httpBackend) {
    httpLocalBackend = $httpBackend;
}));

it('should get stuff', function () {
    var url = '/api/stuff';
    var httpResponse = [{ "stuffId": 1 }, { "stuffId": 2 }];
    httpLocalBackend.expectGET(url).respond(200, httpResponse);
    $scope.getStuff();
    expect($scope.stuff.length).toBe(2);
    //httpLocalBackend.flush();
} );
```

Now, obviously, I changed variable names and such since this is for work, but hopefully this is enough information for anybody to help me. I can provide more if needed. I also get a second error when uncommenting the .flush() line, but I'll get to that a bit later.

Any help is greatly appreciated and thanks in advance!

EDIT:

Finally got it working! Here's my final code:

```
it('should get stuff', function () {
    var url = '/api/stuff';
    var httpResponse = [{ "stuffId": 1 }, { "stuffId": 2 }];
    httpLocalBackend.expectGET(url).respond(200, httpResponse);
    $scope.getStuff();
    httpLocalBackend.flush();
    expect($scope.stuff.length).toBe(2);
} );
```

EDIT 2:
I ran into another problem, which I think may have been the root cause of this. See [Unit test failing when function called on startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25794501/unit-test-failing-when-function-called-on-startup)

Comment: can you try putting you expect *after* $httpBackend.flush() ?

Comment: You need to flush it before expecting the changes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to place httpLocalBackend.flush() statement before expect($scope.stuff.length).toBe(2). Once you make a request you need to flush it for the data to be available in your client code.

```
it('should get stuff', function () {
    var url = '/api/roles';
    var httpResponse = [{ "stuffId": 1 }, { "stuffId": 2 }];
    scope.getStuff(); //Just moved this from after expectGET
    httpLocalBackend.expectGET(url).respond(200, httpResponse);
    httpLocalBackend.flush();
    expect($scope.stuff.length).toBe(2);
} );
```

Try this.

Comment: Error: Unexpected request: GET /api/stuff
No more request expected

Comment: I have an example which works like this:
1) I call a function making a get request such as scope.functionThatMakesAGetRequest()
2) Then I have something like this:
$httpBackend.expect('GET', '/some/url/'+data)
                            .respond(200, {response_data: false});
3) Then I do $httpBackend.flush();

Comment: Sorry so can you also try just putting scope.getStuff() before the expectGET? It works for me.

Comment: I got the same error still. I did change expectGET to whenGET and now the only error i'm getting is "No pending request to flush !" But i'm not sure if that's a step forward or backwards..

Comment: I changed it back to expectGET, and moved the call to the function back to after the expectGET. So, expectGET, call function, flush, expect(whatever).toBe(whatever). I'll update my question with the new code, then mark your answer as accepted, since I wouldn't have gotten it without you. Thanks so much!