# Testing angular controller with $resource and $promise using angular-text-patterns

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I am following the [angular-test-patterns](https://github.com/daniellmb/angular-test-patterns) guide, and I get it working with my first controller test. But when I write the next test, I get the error:

> TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating '$scope.pages.$promise')

The problem then I know is the following line:

> $scope.busy = $scope.pages.$promise;

But I don't know how to deal with this, especially since I am very new in test issues with JavaScript. I looking for a correct and viable way of doing this, to point me in the right direction.

The controller:

```js
angular.module('webvisor')
    .controller('page-list-controller', function($scope,Page){

        $scope.pages = Page.query();
        $scope.busy = $scope.pages.$promise;

    });
```

Service:

```js
angular.module('webvisor').
    factory('Page', ['$resource', 'apiRoot', function($resource, apiRoot) {
        var apiUrl = apiRoot + 'pages/:id/:action/#';
        return $resource(apiUrl,
            {id: '@id'},
            {update: {method: 'PUT'}}
        );
    }]);
```

Test:

```js
'use strict';

describe('Controller: page-list-controller', function () {
    var ctrl, scope, rootScope, Page;

    beforeEach(function () {

        module('webvisor');
        module(function ($provide) {
            $provide.value('Page', new MockPage());
        });

        inject(function ($controller, _Page_) {
            scope = {};
            rootScope = {};
            Page = _Page_;
            ctrl = $controller('page-list-controller', {
                $scope: scope,
                $rootScope: rootScope
            });
        });

    });

    it('should exist', function () {
        expect(!!ctrl).toBe(true);
    });

    describe('when created', function () {

        // Add specs

    });
});
```

Mock:

```js
MockPage = function () {
    'use strict';

    // Methods
    this.query = jasmine.createSpy('query'); // I dont know if this is correct

    return this;
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Mox, your solution would look like this:

```
describe('Controller: page-list-controller', function () {
  var mockedPages = []; // This can be anything

  beforeEach(function () {
    mox
    .module('webvisor')
    .mockServices('Page') // Mock the Page service instead of $httpBackend!
    .setupResults(function () {
      return {
        Page: { query: resourceResult(mockedPages) }
      };
    })
    .run();

    createScope();
    createController('page-list-controller');
  });

  it('should get the pages', function () {
    expect(this.$scope.pages).toEqual(resourceResult(mockedPages));
  });
});
```

As you see, Mox has abstracted away all those boilerplate injections like `$rootScope` and `$controller`. Futhermore there is support for testing resources and promises out of the box.

### Improvements

I advise you not to put the resource result directly on the scope, but resolve it as a promise:

```
$scope.busy = true;
Pages.query().$promise
  .then(function (pages) {
    $scope.pages = pages;
    $scope.busy = false;
  });
```

The Mox test is just this:

```
expect(this.$scope.busy).toBe(true);
this.$scope.$digest(); // Resolve the promise
expect(this.$scope.pages).toBe(mockedPages);
expect(this.$scope.busy).toBe(false);
```

NB: You also can store the result of `createScope()` into a `$scope` var and reuse that everywhere, instead of accessing `this.$scope`.

Comment: Even better than resolving the promise in your controller, resolve it in your route using the 'resolve' property.

Comment: That's a decision on functional a level and a little out of scope for this question: do you want to resolve the route after the Page resource is resolved? (-> resolve in route)
Or is the Page resource one of the resources that is required for a part of the page, showing a spinner in a container before it is resolved? (-> resolve in ctrl)

Comment: Thank you very much @FrankvanWijk!

Answer (score 1):

After some research and many try and error cases, I answer myself with a possible solution, but I expect to find some more usable and not too repetitive soon. For now, I am satisfied with this, using `$httpBackend`.

Test:

```
'use strict';

describe('Controller: page-list-controller', function () {
    var ctrl, scope, rootScope, httpBackend, url;

    beforeEach(function () {
        module('webvisor');
        inject(function ($controller, $httpBackend, apiRoot) {
            scope = {};
            rootScope = {};
            httpBackend = $httpBackend;
            url = apiRoot + 'pages/#';
            ctrl = $controller('page-list-controller', {
                $scope: scope,
                $rootScope: rootScope
            });
        });
    });

    it('should exist', function () {
        expect(!!ctrl).toBe(true);
    });

    describe('when created', function () {

        it('should get pages', function () {
            var response = [{ 'name': 'Page1' }, { 'name': 'Page2' }];
            httpBackend.expectGET(url).respond(200, response);
            httpBackend.flush();
            expect(scope.pages.length).toBe(2);
        });

    });
});
```

I found this solution reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25775462/httpbackend-in-angularjs-jasmine-unit-test). This work very well, and for now, satisfied me. In future, I tried somethig like those:

- [angular-easy-test](https://github.com/EventMobi/angular-easy-test)
- [mox](https://github.com/fvanwijk/mox)

Comment: Gonzalves you found another solution?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I'm working with this one. By the way, it's good to see you here teacher :)